# In First render it shows "undefined" and in second render it shows "data" in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that when I send Array of data as prop and console.log it in another component , it first shows "undefined" and then it shows the data. I get data from API and then send it as prop to another component. I already removed **React.strictMode** from index.js file but it still keeps happening.

for example :

```
const menu = [
{name : "firstFood"},{name:"Second Food"}
]
```

`<MenuTable menu ={menu} />`

and in other component I console.log it.

```
const MenuTable = (props)=>{
console.log(props.menu)
}
```

In first render it shows **undefined**
then it shows **data**

Comment: If you're getting it from an API then on the initial render it's not going to be defined yet

Comment: then what is its solution?

Comment: You can use conditional rendering, something like: `data ? <MyComponent data={data} /> : <div>Loading...</div>`

Comment: thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote:

```
 const [menu, setMenu] = useState()
```

Then you call the api and `setMenu(response)` with the data response.
Therefore, `menu`, at first, is `undefined`. You should try `useState([])`, then the first render of menu is  `[]`.